# Java InputStream

Tags: java, inputstream

I was reading a tutorial for using I/O streams in java and stumbled upon the following code for inputstream:

```
    InputStream input = new FileInputStream("c:\\data\\input-file.txt");
    int data = input.read(); 
    while(data != -1){
    data = input.read();
     }
```

The tutorial mentions that InputStream returns only one byte at a time. So if I want to receive more bytes at a time, is that possible using a different method call?

Comment: Did you look in the [documentation for InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html)?

Comment: Thanks for the link. It clearly mentions how to read 'n' bytes.

Comment: I forgot to answer your question: 'yes'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `read(byte[])` overload of the `read()` method. Try the following:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int bytes_read = 0;
while((bytes_read=input.read(buffer))!= -1)
{
// Do something with the read bytes here
}
```

Further you can channel your `InputStream` into a `DataInputStream` to do more specific tasks like reading integers, doubles, Strings etc.

```
DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(input);
dis.readInt();
dis.readUTF();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D%29) method with an array of bytes. It returns the number of bytes read from the array which isnt always the same length as your array so its important you store that number.

```
InputStream input = new FileInputStream("c:\\data\\input-file.txt");
int numRead; 
byte [] bytes = new byte[512];
while((numRead = input.read(bytes)) != -1){
     String bytesAsString = new String(bytes, 0, numRead);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in the official doc here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html
You can use read(int n) or read(byte[], int, int)